# How do I vertically center a modal using jQuery, independent of scrolling height?

Tags: jquery, css, popup, modal-dialog

I want to vertically center a modal. If the window height is sufficient to require scrolling, the popup always appears near the top. This means I will need to scroll up to see it.

```
var winH = $(window).height(),
    winW = $(window).width();
$(".popup").css('top', winH / 2 - $(".popup").height() / 2);
$(".popup").css('left', winW / 2 - $(".popup").width() / 2);
```

CSS:

```
.popup {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:600px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go with "`position: fixed`".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you already found your answer, but since I have it. 
Here's a working JS fiddle version: [Live Version](http://jsfiddle.net/3YjMM/19/)